# ¿Cómo quitar los datos repetidos en un JSON y sumar sus cantidades en PHP/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el siguiente JSON (Mostrare un dd de la variable $data_concepts):

```
array:3 [
  0 => {#2408
    +"total": "1300"
    +"concepto": "AHORRO SOLIDARIO 1 B"
    +"alias": "2AS"
    +"tipo": 2
    +"code": "2AS"
  }
  1 => {#2377
    +"total": "700"
    +"concepto": "AHORRO SOLIDARIO 1 M"
    +"alias": "2AS"
    +"tipo": 2
    +"code": "2AS.0"
  }
  2 => {#2391
    +"total": "9815.670000000002"
    +"concepto": "AHORRO SOLIDARIO 2 B"
    +"alias": "24S"
    +"tipo": 2
    +"code": "24S."
  }
]
```

Estoy intentando agrupar los datos por medio del alias es decir, si el campo alias es repetido, obtener otro JSON con un solo alias y la suma del **campo total** de todos ellos.

Es decir, algo como esto:

```
array:2 [
      0 => {#2408
        +"total": "2000"
        +"concepto": "AHORRO SOLIDARIO 1 B"
        +"alias": "2AS"
        +"tipo": 2
        +"code": "2AS"
      }
      1 => {#2391
        +"total": "9815.670000000002"
        +"concepto": "AHORRO SOLIDARIO 2 B"
        +"alias": "24S"
        +"tipo": 2
        +"code": "24S."
      }
    ]
```

Estoy intentando de esta manera:

```
$conceptss= [];
  foreach ($data_concepts as $clave => $conceptss) {
                if (!empty($conceptss->alias)) {
                    if(!empty($concepts)) {
                        if (in_array($conceptss->alias, $concepts[$clave])) {
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            array_push($concepts, $conceptss);
                            // dd($concepts);
                        }
                    } else {
                        array_push($concepts, $conceptss);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Pero esto arroja un error, ¿Alguna idea o  consejo? Cualquier ayuda me sirve y se agradece mucho, gracias.

Los datos los obtengo desde una consulta a mi base de datos, la consulta es la siguiente:

```
  $data_concepts = DB::table('processed_payroll_concepts')
                ->select(DB::raw('sum(processed_payroll_concepts.amount) as Total, processed_payroll_concepts.name as Concepto,  processed_payroll_concepts.alias as Alias,  processed_payroll_concepts.cat_concept_type_id as Tipo,  processed_payroll_concepts.code as Code'))
                ->leftJoin('processed_payrolls', 'processed_payrolls.id', '=', 'processed_payroll_concepts.processed_payroll_id')
                ->where('processed_payrolls.payroll_id', $id)
                // ->whereNotNull('alias')
                ->groupBy('processed_payroll_concepts.name')
                ->groupBy('processed_payroll_concepts.alias')
                ->groupBy('processed_payroll_concepts.cat_concept_type_id')
                ->groupBy('processed_payroll_concepts.code')
                ->get();
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estas generando ese JSON? ¿Es la respuesta de alguno de tus controladores?

Comment: Es el resultado de una consulta a la base de datos, agregaré la consulta.

Comment: No entiendo que quieras esa salida... ¿no te conformas con los totales y ya esta?   Lo digo porque lo valores de `code` y `concepto` son distintos en los alias coincidentes, y no se que criterio quieres seguir para conservar unos u otros en la salida final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como decia en los comentarios, no entiendo que quieras esa salida, pues los valores de `code` y `concepto` son distintos.

Aun así, esto creo que puede funcionarte bien:

```
$output = [];
foreach ($data_concepts as $clave => $conceptss) {
    if(!isset($output[$conceptss->alias])) {
        $output[$conceptss->alias] = $conceptss;
    } else {
        $output[$conceptss->alias]->total += $conceptss->total;
    }
}
print_r(array_values($output));
$json = json_encode(array_values($output));
```

pues genera esta salida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 2000
            [concepto] => AHORRO SOLIDARIO 1 B
            [alias] => 2AS
            [tipo] => 2
            [code] => 2AS
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 9815.670000000002
            [concepto] => AHORRO SOLIDARIO 2 B
            [alias] => 24S
            [tipo] => 2
            [code] => 24S.
        )
)
```

que viene a coindicir con lo que preguntas.

**Explicación**

- Primero definimos e inicializamos una variable del tipo array denominada `$output` donde iremos almacenando los datos de cada ciclo, relacionados mediante claves que coincidan con la propiedad `alias`

```
$output = [];
```

- Luego iniciamos el bucle. Y mediante un condicional comprobamos si, en la variable `$output` existe la clave que se corresponda con el valor de la propiedad `alias` del objeto iterado en ese ciclo del bucle.

```
    if(!isset($output[$conceptss->alias])) {
```

- Si no existe entramos en el condicional y la creamos, asignándole el valor del primer objeto iterado completo con todas sus variables y valores:

```
        $output[$conceptss->alias] = $conceptss;
```

- Y si existe querra decir que ya contiene al menos un objeto completo, y por lo tanto podremos sumarle el nuevo total que nos venga en ese nuevo objeto iterado en ese ciclo y que coincide en su alias:

```
    } else {
        $output[$conceptss->alias]->total += $conceptss->total;
    }
```

- Y así hasta que terminen los ciclos del bucle. Después, para librarnos de las claves de alias que hemos estado usando, lo imprimimos usando [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php) que nos imprimirá un nuevo array indexado numéricamente, tal como estaba solicitado en la pregunta.

```
print_r(array_values($output));
```

Luego, si lo necesitas en formato **json**, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$json = json_encode(array_values($output));
```

Ya nos diras si te sirve.